# Linq2Sql Join Into DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 tables that I need to grab columns from based on cid which is ClientID in both tables. My code below works in displaying the table but _DOCID is always null. What am I missing?

```
            public IQueryable ReturnCart(int cid)
    {
        try 
        {
            var result = from c in veps.ecomCarts
                         join d in veps.lawFirmClientDocumentPurchaseds on c.ClientID equals d.ID into cd
                         from d in cd.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where c.ClientID == cid
                            select new
                         {
                             _DOCID = d.ID,
                             _ID = c.ID,
                             _CID = c.ClientID,
                             _UPC = c.UPC,
                             _Description = c.Description,
                             _Quantity = c.Quantity,
                             _UnitPrice = c.UnitPrice,
                             _Discount = c.Discount,
                             _Total = c.Total,
                             _InProgress = c.InProgress,
                             _dts = c.dts

                         };


            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _IsError = true;
            _ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Updated Issue Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQLef.png)

Comment: "*based on cid which is **ClientID** in **both** tables*". But inside the query you use `on c.ClientID equals d.ID`. So how it should be?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Should of read: join d in veps.lawFirmClientDocumentPurchaseds on c.ClientID equals d.ClientID into cd

Comment: Ok, and you say the corrected left join always returns null for the right side? This usually happens if there is no matching record from the "right" table (that's the whole reason of the left outer join), are you sure you have data in `lawFirmClientDocumentPurchaseds` with `ClientID` matching the passed `cid`?

Comment: Well interesting development. I know have the _DOCID working but I am seeing 2 records with different DOCID's. I will post an image of the issue if I can.

Comment: Well, your `lawFirmClientDocumentPurchaseds` table may contain two records with the same `ClientId` but different `ID`

Comment: That is correct. There are multiple docs per client so I want to display all cart contents and the doc that goes with it from the doc table.

Comment: *multiple docs per client* So what is ***the** doc*?

Comment: ecomCarts hold clients shopping cart items and lawFirmDocumentPurchaseds hold the document associated with each shopping cart item. The grid should display each eComCart item for a client and the associating lawFirmDocumentPurchaseds ID. The doc is just a record with an ID as its primary key.

Comment: OK, I didn't ask it clearly enough. If there are multiple docs per client, how do you find THE (= one) "document associated with each shopping cart item"?

Comment: Using the IQueryable in my code above. c.ClientID == d.ClientID or maybe im not understanding what you mean. To me it seems simple. 2 tables both with ClientID columns. List all records in table 1 plus add the ID of table 2 for each record based on cid. Maybe my code above is incorrect. its listing 2 of each record instead of adding the ID from table 1. I thought the join did that.

Answer (score 0):

So after much thinking in my sleep I realized that the answer to my issue was GroupBy Nested. Here is my final code.

```
public IQueryable ReturnCart(int cid)
    {
        try 
        {
            var result = (from c in veps.ecomCarts
                          where c.ClientID == cid
                          select new 
                          {

                              _ID = c.ID,
                              _CID = c.ClientID,
                              _UPC = c.UPC,
                              _Description = c.Description,
                              _Quantity = c.Quantity,
                              _UnitPrice = c.UnitPrice,
                              _Discount = c.Discount,
                              _Total = c.Total,
                              _InProgress = c.InProgress,
                              _dts = c.dts,

                              lcdp = from d in veps.lawFirmClientDocumentPurchaseds
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         _DOCID = d.ID
                                     }
                          });

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _IsError = true;
            _ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thank you Ivan for posting. You actually helped me think of what needed to be done. So thanks for that.